# Pug (formerly Jade) Variables Not Working (Interpolating) Correctly Inside Anchor Href

Tags: node.js, express, pug, pugjs

I'm playing around with Node and Express and I'm using the Pug (formerly Jade) templating engine to render my html. Everything has been working fine up until I started trying to inject variables into the `href` of my anchor links. Whats odd is that if I change my Express app `view engine` to `jade` then things start working as expected.

Based upon [other articles](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/1028) I've read the issue appears to be an interpolation issue, however I can't seem to find a resource or documentation that shows how to correctly fix this issue.

Ex.

I'm pulling in data from a `rooms` json array and then using a `for` loop to cycle through each array element and output the data for each room. Using `jade` the following works.

```
table.table.table-striped
  thead
    tr
      th Name
      th Id
  tbody
    each room in rooms
      tr
        td(style="width: 50px;")
          a(href!="/admin/rooms/delete/#{room.id}") Delete
        td #{allTitleCase(room.name)}
        td #{room.id}
```

Using `pug` the above does NOT work correctly. Specifically the `a(href='/admin/rooms/delete/#{room.id}') Delete` link doesn't work correctly. Instead of injecting the room id into the link href, it literally outputs *#{room.id}* as the end part the `href` link.

Any ideas how to fix this in `pug`?

Note that I've tried all of the following using `pug` but none of these options have worked.

- `a(href="/admin/rooms/delete/#{room.id}") Delete`
- `a(href!="/admin/rooms/delete/#{room.id}") Delete`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

UPDATE: Pug 2.0 introduced breaking changes to how interpolation is handled.

Based on [the changelog](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2305), any of the following *should* work:

```
// to solve OP's problem, the following can be used:
a(href="/admin/rooms/delete/" + room.id) Delete

// Here are a few additional scenarios which use the new API 
// for anyone stumbling across this answer in the future
- var href = "/admin/rooms/delete/" + room.id;
a(href=href)
a(href=`${href}`) // Node.js/io.js ≥ 1.0.0
a(href=href + '?foo=bar')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately this didn't work for me. While it did work on the jade-lang website, it doesn't appear to work in my Express app running `pug` as the `view engine`. I think it worked on the jade-lang website because that's actually using `jade` and not `pug`.

Comment: Have you read through [the Pug 2.0 changelog](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2305)?

Comment: After checking out the changelog like you suggested, I figured it out... I changed the anchor link to `a(href="/admin/rooms/delete/" + room.id) Delete` and this worked. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. Can you edit your answer to include the correct code? If so I'll go ahead and mark your answer correct.

Comment: @Corey OK - updated. I left the additional examples for anyone else who runs into this issue in the future.